# Disable editing profile for second time

Tags: users, profiles

Hi and thanks every one . i wonder if there was any way to disable editing profile for users of my site for a second time . because after i approve a user he/she changes his avatar to inappropriate photo !  any suggestion really appreciated .

Comment: A couple of options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389753/disable-profile-editing-for-one-single-account

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/disallow-user-from-editing-their-own-profile-information

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely disable the user from editing their profile, you can remove the user profile page.  See a similar question here: [disallow user from editing their own profile information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/disallow-user-from-editing-their-own-profile-information.).